# Display ascii value into Spring input

Tags: spring, jsp, ascii, quote

Using spring form, we display an input like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
 ...
<form:input type="text" cssClass="w50" path="lastName" cssErrorClass="w50 error" placeholder="${msgLastName}" />
```

Sometimes, the users lastname value may content single quote, eg "Job's". This probkem is that we clean the lastname with the OWASP HTML Project, which causes the lastname to be

```
Job&#39;s
```

When the input is displayed into the browser, the ascii value is also displayed - whici is bad. I would like to display simply "Job's" into the input.

I tested with a simple JSP input, eg.

```
<input type="text" cssClass="w50" value="${myobject.lastName}" cssErrorClass="w50 error" placeholder="${msgLastName}" />
```

In this case, the rendering is fine.

My conclusion is that the problem comes from spring, but how to avoid it?

Comment: Add htmlEscape attribute your input tag and try again <form:input type="text" htmlEscape="false" ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.

Spring HTML-escapes the values, it doesn't really output

```
Job&#39;s
```

but

```
Job&amp;#39;s
```

As there is an HTML character, it isn't parsed as ascii.

Using Chrome, if I inspect the DOM I cannot see the

```
&amp;
```

but if I "edit as HTML" then I see it.